# Why does this loop twice? Why don't the methods run?

Tags: loops, while-loop, user-input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    String choice = "";
            while(x!=0) {

            System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter help for commands.");
            choice = userInput.next().toLowerCase();

            if(choice.equals("go right")) method(); 
            if(choice.equals("go left")) method();
            if(choice.equals("go forwards")) method();
            if(choice.equals("go backwards")) method();
            if(choice.equals("help")) System.out.println("I can print!");

            x--;
            System.out.println("Value of x: " + x);

        }
}
```

The code above seems to run twice, x is reduced by two before the scanner asks for user input again.

```
 public void method(){
      System.out.println("methoding");
}
```

Additionally, the method doesn't run when called from an if statement but the print statement will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method isn't being called because `userInput.next()` will only return the next word (ie. until there's a space). You should look into `.nextLine()` or `.useDelimiter()` to change this behaviour and return an entire line.

This also explains why x decreases twice -- if you type "go right", that counts as two separate `.next()`s.

Comment: I love you with my whole heart.

Answer (score 0):

1. **You must add `static` to `method`**, because now it's an instance method and can't be called from a static function like `main`.
2. **Don't check `x != 0`.** It's possible it works, but in a complicated loop, where `x` can reduce more than one time, it may pass 0, go into negatives and never end the loop. Check `x > 0` instead.
3. **Use a `for` loop instead `while`**, if you need to increment/decrement the loop controlling variable at the end of loop.